# Got:warning, no ros configured for this environment message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ran ros on Ubuntu 12.04 before, and when I would like to use it again today, I got this message:
Warning, no ros configured for this environment. show on my terminal.

I am a new user of both ros and ubuntu, this may a stupid question. but please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62286/got:warning,-no-ros-configured-for-this-environment-message/) by [Haojun Guan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2244/haojun-guan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely a problem with your environment variables.  The exact way you need to set the environment variables depends on which distro of ROS you are running (fuerte, groovy, etc.).  If you go back to the install instructions for your version, you will notice that there is a step about "sourcing" a `setup.bash` file.  For example in section 1.5 of the [fuerte install instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu), you'll a description about how to properly configure your environment.  Note that as the link mentions, if you don't add changes to your environment to your `.bashrc` file, then you will have to change them in every terminal you want to use ROS in.

ROS needs [environment variables](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) such as `ROS_DISTRO`, `ROS_MASTER_URI`, `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, and more all to be set to function properly.  You can check all currently set environment variables with the `env` command.  You can also do something like `echo $ROS_DISTRO` to see just one environment variable. To see all ROS environment variables you could use

```
env | grep ROS
```

Also note that even if your environment variables are all set, they need to be set in agreement with your actual current system setup.  For example, if you installed Fuerte following the install instructions, and then switched to Groovy, it's possible your `.bashrc` file has conflicting commands in it.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1